# C#: Error on converting string to dictionary delimited by first occurrence of a char

Tags: c#, string

I have a string:

```
"abc:def,ABC:DEF,Time:03:04:59,Date:01:01:2016"
```

I want the resultant string to be:

```
abc:def
ABC:DEF
Time:03:04:59
Date:01:01:2016
```

I am getting compilation error

> The best overloaded method match for string.Split(params char[]) has some invalid arguments

when I try the following code:

```
Result = string.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
               .Select(part => part.Split(':',2))
               .ToDictionary(split => split[0], split => split[1]);
```

pointing at `part.Split(':',2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to split that string is the following

```
string test = "abc:def,ABC:DEF,Time:03:04:59,Date:01:01:2016";
var Result = test.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
           .Select(part => part.Split(new char[] { ':'}, 2))
           .ToDictionary(split => split[0], split => split[1]);
```

All of the [Split overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) that take more than one parameter don't allow the first parameter to be a single char (or better, a **params char[]**) but require the first parameter to be an array of chars (or strings)

Comment: I struggle with lambda expressions and I thought it was something to do with that. BTW., sad that 'Split overload' that takes more than one param doesn't specify that it needs to be a character array or string. Thank you.